# Convert ASP.NET Web Application to ASP.NET WebSite

Tags: c#, asp.net

**SCENARIO:** A developer at work has created an three-tier *ASP.NET Web Application* which plugs into the  company website, however the rest of the site was done as an *ASP.NET Website.* For clearity, his portion used Web Application (compiled into single .dll) and the rest of the site is WebSite (seperate .dlls). I do not wish to recompile the website every time a change is made to a page.

> **QUESTION:** Is it possible to convert a Web Application
>   to a Website without rewriting the entire application?

**TRIED:**

1. Created WebSite and copied & pasted files over
2. Changed'CodeBehind' to 'CodeFile'
3. Deleted .designer.cs from pages and controls
4. Checked References

Comment: Anything's possible, but IMHO you are going in the wrong direction.  You should be upgrading your Website into the Web Application.

Comment: You say you tried 4 things, but what was the outcome?

Comment: Did you move the classes into App_Code? Otherwise, looks like you've got the right steps.

Comment: @MikeC - I respectfully disagree. There are many cases where the single dll issue is a big bother. I had a similar problem recently  when wanting to upload a single change on a website and having to recompile the entire web app and mind you, it was a shared code situation...

Comment: MikeC - I tend agree given that Google only provides 'web to app' and not 'app to web', but as Ted said, when you have a team trying to make individual changes to certain modules of the site, recompiling for every change becomes tedius. Regardless, this is something I have been tasked to do, so I hold no opinion in the matter. @Mark Brackett - What do you mean by "move the classes into App_Code"? Thus far, I have solved most errors, however 'Unknown server tag' errors remain. I have only been doing ASP.net for a short time, so consider me noobish.

Comment: Do you use source control? Automated builds? Continuous integration? If so, then your scenario is trivial and Web Applications are the way to go. It sounds like your ALM processes aren't that sophisticated.

Comment: @MikeC - The funny bit is that Web Sites were actually the ASP.NET 2.0 "upgrade" to Web Applications. Then folks complained, so MS had to put Web Applications back in VS 2005. Officially, both are supported and have their place - in reality, all the tooling surrounding web projects has been focused on Web Applications. Personally, I use both depending on the use case - this has some decent info on the actual differences and pros/cons: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx

Comment: @JoshCampbell Web Sites rely on an `App_Code` directory as a special directory that will compile your source code on the fly.  You'll need to add one to the root of your web application, and move all .cs or .vb files to that folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok - assuming you have a backup, this is how I would tackle it:

1. Delete the csproj file
2. From within Windows Explorer, delete any `designer.cs` files
3. Still in Explorer, create an App_Code folder at the root of the site
4. Find any `*.cs` files that aren't code behinds (eg., `.ascx.cs` or `.aspx.cs`) and move them into the App_Code folder
5. Open in Visual Studio as Web Site project
6. Verify .NET FX version
7. Change `CodeBehind=` to `CodeFile=` in any `.aspx` or `.ascx` files
8. Readd any 3rd party references

There's some potential complications around Global.asax, ASHX handlers (need to be inline) and referencing pages and controls. You'll have to deal with those manually, I'm afraid - but if it's a smallish effort, it should be easily doable.